# Extracting a year from a DateField in django in the database

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I know its possible to use [lookups to filter a DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) in the database by year like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__year=2000) # Returns all objects with a year of 2000
```

But, I want to the extract that when using a [`values()` call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values):

```
MyModel.objects.all().values('label','date__year') # Fails!

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'year' into field. Join on 'date' not permitted.
```

I've tried making a custom lookup, but that doesn't apply to a values call.

How can I extract just the year in this kind of query?

---

edit: To be clear, I know I could do this a million ways in Python iterating over the queryset once its back from the database. But I don't want to do this.

Comment: Year chaining lookup was introduced in django 1.9: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#year Which version of django are you on ?

Comment: I'm on 1.8 at the moment, and I could have sworn filtering was possible. I'll update the question, but the core problem still remains.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if you want.

The syntax would be this:

```
[(x['label'], x['date'].year) for MyModel.objects.all().values('label','date')]
```

Comment: No, I need this as a queryset call. I can't extract it using python.